# DragonBones/createJS show wrong sprites on iOS when using big textures

Tags: ios, html, flash, easeljs, createjs

I am creating a HTML5 application with complex animations exported from Flash. When trying to use big textures/skeletons exported via DragonBones (as png+JSON) and using DragonBones.js and the createJS bridge for display, animations look great on Windows/Android but on iOS (iPhone 4S/iPad 2) they display the wrong sprites and generally mess up the animation.

[Here is an example](http://koro.me/stuff/animpedia/) - click the 'play' button to make the animation run along with the sound once it's loaded. It's wrapped with a lot of framework code (sorry)

Thanks, Oded

Comment: I had a similar issue once(though that was some time ago with iOS5/6: On the iPad2 the maximum texture size is 2048x2048px (this is a hardware/OS-limitation and not CreateJS-related) - on iPad3 it's 4096px
Try using a smaller texture and let us know if that worked

Comment: I tested it w/ iPad and iPhones running iOS 7 and I can confirm these numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad2 the maximum texture size is 2048x2048px (this is a hardware/OS-limitation and not CreateJS-related) - on iPad3 it's 4096px